# linking error with NDK (r19c): cannot find -lpthread

Tags: c++, linux, android-ndk

I have a C++ project with CMake build system. When I compile using GCC it compiles fine. But when I tried to use NDK toolchain, it shows the following error.

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/my_app
/opt/r19c/linux-x86_64/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld:
cannot find -lpthread
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Don't use `-lpthread`, use `-pthread`. Not sure it helps but it's the best way to include `pthread`s anyway. If that doesn't work, just try building without explicitly mentioning `pthread`. The Android NDK may have built-in support.

Comment: Unrelated: Android NDK r19c is ancient. Please update to a more recent one.